# How to re-populate listbox in UWP C# after returning to the frame?

Tags: c#, listbox, uwp

I have composite settings which re-populate data for Text Boxes and Text Blocks, but failing when trying to re-populate the list boxes. Here is some code: inside "OnNavigatedTo"

```
{
ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = (ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["CompositeSettings"];

                    if (composite == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox("No data!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtBox1.Text = composite["text1"]?.ToString();
                        txtBox2.Text = composite["text2"]?.ToString();

                        //Here are the issues
                        lstOfData1.ItemsSource = composite["myListOfData1"]?.ToString();
                        lstOfData2.ItemsSource = composite["myListOfData2"]?.ToString();

                    }
```

Inside "OnNavigatingFrom"

```
{

 ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = new ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
            composite["text1"] = txtBox1.Text;
            composite["text2"] = txtBox2.Text;

            composite["myListOfData1"] = myListOfData1;
            composite["myListOfData2"] = myListOfData2;

            localSettings.Values["CompositeSettings"] = composite;

        }
```

So, the txtBoxes re-populate fine, but the listBoxes are empty. Do I foreach through the composite settings? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*myListOfData1* and *myListOfData2* should be some kind of collections, but in the OnNavigatingTo method, your are casting them to strings.This works for the textboxes, because the Text property is a string.

You just need to cast it to the correct type, e.g. *List< YourDataObject >*, or something like that...

Comment: Thank you Philip, you got on the right track. I solved the issue as follows:

Comment: //On NavigatedTo:
    {
    ...
     listBox.ItemsSource = composite["myList"];
     listBox2.ItemsSource = composite["myList2"];
    ...
    }

Comment: // OnNavigatingFrom:
    {
    ...
      List<string> comp1 = new List<string>();
      foreach (string item in listBox.Items)
          {
              comp1.Add(item);
          }
              composite["myList"] = comp1.ToArray();
              List<string> comp2 = new List<string>();
              foreach (string item in listBox2.Items)
              {
                  comp2.Add(item);
              }
              composite["myList2"] = comp2.ToArray();
              localSettings.Values["CompositeSettings"] = composite;
    ...
    }